# Moving an UIView - newbie iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Hey guys... today is my first day hacking away on the iphone SDK. Having a blast but have a quick question.

I'm trying to move an UIView around the screen dynamically by sending it information from a slider. My slider is working fine but I cant seem to figure out how to get the UIView to move.

My .h file...

```
@interface Slider_BallViewController : UIViewController 
{
   IBOutlet UISlider *theslider;
   IBOutlet UITextField *ytext;
   IBOutlet UIView *theball;
}
- (IBAction)moveVert:(id)sender;
```

My .m file...

```
- (IBAction)moveVert:(id)sender
{
 int progressAsInt = (int)(theslider.value);
 NSString *newText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", progressAsInt];
 ytext.text = newText;

 theball.frame.origin.y += progressAsInt;
}
```

I get an error on the frame.origin line in my .m file that says... lvalue required as left operand assignment. Not sure what im doing wrong.

Any help is great, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify a UIView's frame property, you should do it by following:

```
CGRect curFrame = theball.frame;
curFrame.origin.y += progressAsInt;
theball.frame = curFrame;
```